# Echoing HTML code vs. leaving it out of PHP

Tags: php

Should I prefer one of these snippets over the other and why?

1.

```
function render()
{
    echo "<div>$content</div>";
}
```

2.

```
function render()
{
    ?>
    <div><?= $content ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Consider Include files or just XPHP. so basically we have 4 options now :)

Comment: What would be the benefits of the options you're proposing?

Comment: In this setup I would prefer the first (just for cleaner code). It's even better to completely leave HTML out of your PHP code, for example by using a templateParser and instead of `echo "<div>$content</div>";` you would put something as `$tpl->NewBlock("CONTENT");` `$tpl->assign(array('content' => $content));` (this is an example for TemplateParser). Or since this is a class (at least I think it is): return the value and add it in HTML in another file.

Comment: Breaking out of a PHP block in a class or function definition to me is just absolute taboo.

Comment: I prefer include files (since I'm still not very familiar with XPHP). Include files will serve as your "View" files, with this, you will get the MVC-feel (separation of concerns). Your CSS, client-side scripts, etc is on the view files. All data is generated in PHP functions and then later passed onto the file. However, using include or require inside a function will not supply global variables to the file, you need to $GLOBALS or global $var;

Answer (score 8):

Both are not a good idea. 
Cause function is *outputting*. Try make this way:

```
function render( $content_, $style_ )
{
    $res = "<div{$style_}>$content_</div>";
    return $res;
}
```

...

and then:

```
echo render( "Content inside div", " style='color:red;'" )
```

Cause:

1. Function is *calculating* and *returning*, it's main purpose is this.
2. Application is generating, and it can use functions to prepare.
3. Your may need to make some header in the future, and good idea is to have start all output at end of script. Using templating like Smarty, so - will save many time for you :)

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, it's a good idea to keep the contents of each file that makes up your application as uncluttered as possible. Since PHP is a template language and you can have PHP files with wildly different purposes (consider that a file containing pure HTML is a valid PHP file), my personal preference is:

**If you need to create a small bit of HTML in code, don't open and close PHP tags.**

For example, prefer this:

```
function render()
{
    echo "<div>$content</div>";
}
```

over this:

```
function render()
{
    ?><div><?= $content ?></div><?php
}
```

Also observe that on the snippet above I have not included any spaces just after the PHP close tag or before the PHP open tag; generally whitespace is not significant in HTML but it can matter in two cases:

- You want to have nicely indented HTML (sometimes helpful while developing)
- The presence of one or more whitespace character vs none at all creates an extra text node in the DOM tree, which might matter

If you want to include this kind of whitespace in the HTML your source code is going to be a bit ugly on the eyes in any case, but definitely uglier if you go with the close/open tag approach.

**Isolate large pieces of HTML in views and include small bits of logic as necessary there.**

For example, prefer this:

```
<body>
  <div id="blah">
    <ul id="nav">
      <?php foreach ($navItems as $url => $title) : ?>
      <!--
      NOTE:
      You can opt to make the line below a single echo statement
      in PHP rather than HTML with values from PHP substituted
      in various places inside, and in this example it might even
      be better. However, if the output for each item is more complex
      than a li/a pair, it will be far more readable in this form.
      -->
      <li><a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

over this:

```
$output = '<body><div id="blah"><ul id="nav">';
foreach ($navItems as $url => $title) {
    $output .= '<li><a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a></li>
}

echo $output;
```